# Cálculo de adicionais em porcentagem com jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Estou montando uma calculadora de adicionais para um produto, porém os adicionais são calculados em porcentagem. Por exemplo:

> Se o produto for **R$ 50,00** e estiver marcado o *checkbox* que adiciona **40%**, deve alterar a div preço para **R$ 70,00**.

Se caso estiver marcado os dois primeiros *checkbox* (*40% e 15%*), o valor esperado é **R$ 127,50**. A porcentagem deve ter como base o preço original (*no caso de dois ou mais adicionais marcados*).

```
<input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="40" id="adicional1">
  <label class="form-check-label" for="defaultCheck1">
    Adicional 1 - <strong>+40%</strong>
  </label>

<input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="15" id="adicional2">
  <label class="form-check-label" for="defaultCheck1">
    Adicional 2 - <strong>+15%</strong>
  </label>

<input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="30" id="adicional3">
  <label class="form-check-label" for="defaultCheck1">
    Adicional 3 - <strong>+30%</strong>
  </label>

<div id="price">R$ 50,00</div>
```

O código que tentei adaptar e não funcionou, pois ele **soma** os valores e não a **porcentagem**.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.form-check-input').click(function (){
        var total = 0;
        $('.form-check-input:ckecked').each(function(){
            total += parseInt($(this).val());
            var formatado = total.toLocaleString("pt-BR", { style: "currency" , currency:"BRL"});
        });
        $('#price').html(formatado);
    });
});
```

Como transformar esse código para que some porcentagem?

Comment: Antes de mais nada, não use cumprimentos ou saudações, veja [que tipo de comportamento é esperado dos usuários?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/behavior) e  como criar um [mre] para poder elaborar uma pergunta **BOA** e **CLARA**

Comment: para fazer esses "adicionais" é necessário fazer o cálculo de porcentagem primeiro (*para obter o resultado correto, se não irá apenas somar os valores*) a interpretadora não entende que o % refere-se a porcentagem, por isso o cálculo `valor * (porcentagem / 100)` que neste caso `50 * (40 / 100) = 20`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Pelo que entendi da sua pergunta..

é que você deseja calcular **valores** com adicionais (*pelo visto descontos e promoções*). Seu código está apenas **somando** os **valores** e não as **porcentagens**, o interpretador não entende que `%` refere-se a porcentagem (não neste caso). Sua pergunta você não descreve a sua necessidade ou onde você quer chegar, então por isso sugiro que você **NÃO DEIXE** de ver [Como criar um exemplo Mínimo, Completo e Verificável](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) e [Como fazer uma boa pergunta?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

---

Portanto, fiz toda parte do [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript) com as devidas funcionalidades, desde de calcular a porcentagem á somar e imprimir na página!

vale apena dar uma olhada na documentação [MDN Web Docs: Matemática básica no JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Learn/JavaScript/First_steps/Math) para você entender um pouco como funciona os operadores e tudo mais..

```js
var valor = conversor(document.querySelector('#price').innerHTML); // obtem o valor impresso
var valor_inicial = conversor(document.querySelector('#price').getAttribute('valor-inicial')); // obtem o valor inicial armazenado (nao sofre alterações)

// vai percorrer todos os inputs do tipo checkbox (referentes aos adicionais)
document.querySelectorAll('input[type=checkbox]').forEach(input => {
    input.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
        if (input.checked) { // ao ser marcado
            var porcentagem = valor_inicial * (conversor(input.value) / 100); // vai calcular a porcentagem sobre o valor inicial
            valor = valor + porcentagem; // soma o valor com a porcentagem calculada
            document.querySelector('#price').innerHTML = formatCurrency.format(valor); // imprime o resultado na div
        } else { // ao ser desmarcado
            var porcentagem = valor_inicial * (conversor(input.value) / 100); // vai calcular a porcentagem sobre o valor inicial
            valor = valor - porcentagem; // subtrai o valor da porcentagem calculada (resultado no valor anterior)
            document.querySelector('#price').innerHTML = formatCurrency.format(valor); // imprime o resultado na div
        }
    });
})

// vai tratar os valores para que não ocorra erros nos calculos (ex: NaN, undefined)
function conversor(input) {
    if (typeof input == 'number')
        return input;
    
    let res;
    input = input.toString().replace(/[^0-9,.]/g, '');
    if (input.match(/(,)\d{2}$/)) {
        res = input.replace(/\./g, '').replace(',', '.')
    } else {
        res = input.replace(',', '');
    }

    return parseFloat(res);
}


// formata o resultado final para ser impresso em moeda real
const formatCurrency = new Intl.NumberFormat('pt-BR', {
    style: 'currency',
    currency: 'BRL'
});
```

```html
<input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="40" id="adicional1">
<label class="form-check-label" for="defaultCheck1">
  Adicional 1 - <strong>+40%</strong>
</label>

<input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="15">
<label class="form-check-label" for="defaultCheck1">
  Adicional 2 - <strong>+15%</strong>
</label>

<input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="30">
<label class="form-check-label" for="defaultCheck1">
  Adicional 3 - <strong>+30%</strong>
</label>

  <br />
  
<div id="price" valor-inicial="50,00">R$ 50,00</div>
```

<sup>Preservei seu código **HTML** para não fugir muito do seu contexto!</sup>

---

#### Nota! foi adicionado alguns detalhes..

A função `conversor()` para tratar quaisquer entradas de texto ou números não-formatados. Ao desmarcar as **checkboxs** o valor é retornado ao anterior (*sem o adicional independente de quantos estejam marcados, se todos forem desmarcados o valor continuará o mesmo de inicialmente*).

E foi adicionado a função [`getAttribute()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/element/getAttribute) que retornará o valor do argumento específico do elemento, ou seja, o **valor_inicial** pois não teria outra forma de obter o real valor do "produto" após feitas as alterações.

Comment: É quase isso. No exemplo de código que foi enviado, quando desmarcado o adicional, o valor não retorna ao que era antes do cálculo. Obrigado pela lição, desde já.

Comment: @DeyvidHenriquePereira você quer que além de incrementar os adicionais, os remove-lo caso desmarque os checkboxs?

Comment: Sim, o usuário pode querer não adicionar aquele adicional ao produto. Então o cálculo precisa ser flexível.

Comment: é só pegar o `valor = valor - porcentagem` e subtrair que estará removendo a porcentagem do valor. Nota! encontre uma forma de armazenar sempre os valores a cada vez que adiciona-los, assim tem como "saber" o valor antes de adicionar a porcentagem.

Comment: Se lhe ajudou de alguma forma, se possível marque a resposta como aceita e funcional! fica abaixo dos votos, assim poderá está ajudado outros..

Comment: É isso mesmo, quando o valor tem decimais, o resultado não é o esperado.